# What would be the equivalent of "spam" if referring to face-to-face conversation?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

If unsolicited bulk mail in your inbox is referred to as spam, what would be its equivalent for someone  talking indiscriminately, but face-to-face without the intervention of technology.

Comment: blather, babble, logorrhea, prattle,  drivel.

Comment: Hi @Casey Affleck how have you found the answers given so far? Do you know how to cast up and down votes? Please say if you're not sure:)

Answer (score 4):

***Yack, Yack, Yack***  or ***Yacking***

Yack -- Merriam Webster "to talk in a loud way often for a long time"

"Even though I was obviously trying to do the crossword, my seat-mate kept up a constant yack, yack, yack during the entire flight."

"Show the tiniest response, and she will go on yacking forever."

Answer (score 1):

How about "loquaciousness?"

> **loquacious** *adj.*
>
> talking or tending to talk much or freely; talkative
>
> (noun: **loquaciousness**)

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Answer (score 1):

If you need something strong:

**verbal diarrhea**

Answer (score 0):

There is [*bend someone's ear*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bend_someone's_ear):

> (idiomatic) To bore; to talk too long, especially to one particular person.

It's like *prating*, but with a connotation of being unable to politely escape.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of spam, or junk e-mail, seems to be to get attention, for some reason that can only be discovered by clicking on the e-mail.  Teenagers sometimes speak to the entire room, with the apparent hope that someone will pay attention, sometimes with important information, and sometimes not.  I think of it as, "Chatter," since it is meant to gain attention, or simply to entertain, without a whole lot of specific content. But one can only really tell what they want by interrupting the chatter, and asking them.  In a sense, one must click on the chatter.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word *Rant*.

TFD

> 1. To speak or write in an angry or emotionally charged manner; rave.
> 2. To express at length a complaint or negative opinion: "He could rant on the subject of physician-assisted illness" (Paul Theroux).
>      v.tr.
>      To utter or express by ranting: "Adams's fellow Federalists ranted that he was mentally unfit to be president" (Susan Dunn).
>      n.
> 3. Angry, emotionally charged, or tediously negative speech or writing: a speech that was more rant than reason.
> 4. An example of such speech or writing: a rant against the university's policies.

Answer (score 0):

If you take spam to be an attempt to get you to buy something that you don't want, then the person doing all the talking is a salesman.

The stream of words used to sell is known as [*Sales Patter*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+sales+patter&oq=define+sales+patter&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l3.340.2837.0.3015.20.15.0.1.1.0.268.2198.0j8j4.12.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..8.12.2024.0.jBsdQOTEQXY).

I have always understood the phrase to liken the patter of words to the patter of raindrops - meaningless noise.

The phrase is most frequently used in reference to market traders, used car dealers and insurance brokers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **ramble** - **rambled** - **rambled** in some cases.